# Use an underscore variable with a twig filter

Tags: variables, backbone.js, filter, twig, underscore.js

How can I use my underscore variable in a twig filter like :

`{{ <%= tweet.created_at.date %> | translate_date }}`

The error throw is :

`Unexpected token "operator" of value "<" in /Users/ .... .html.twig at line ...`

Comment: I don't get it, twig templates are rendered server-side on php, how can they interact with js client-side code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think you just can't, Dude ;) You can use moment.js to "humanize" and translate your dates. (Relative dates too)

Answer (score 0):

From your error message it's the "<" character that's throwing the error, not the underscored variable. What's wrong with `{{ tweet.created_at.date | translate_date }}` ? Maybe I am missing something, what's the "<%=" for?